# How to change Vim text pointer size in insert mode?

Tags: windows, vim, text-cursor

Does anyone have any idea how to change the thickness of the text pointer in gVim in insert mode? I'm using it on Windows, so maybe there's a Windows trick that may do the job.

Right now it's about 3px wide, whereas I want it 1px wide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out :help gcr for full details.  You'll probably want to edit your existing setting, but here's what worked for me:

```
set gcr=...,i-ci:ver10-Cursor/lCursor,...
```

The ... represents the values that were there before, for the other modes.